# HTML 5 audio re-read

Tags: html, audio-streaming

How to re-read an audio file (.WAV) in HTML 5 if the content is changed but the name is still the same? I have implemented this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function Speak() {
    document.getElementById("Speech").load();
    document.getElementById("Speech").play();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<audio id="Speech" src="speech.wav"></audio>
<button type="button" onclick="Speak()">Speak</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If I change the content of `speech.wav`, the browser still plays the previous content at the click of the button. Is there a way to re-read the audio file?

Answer (score 1):

The most fool-proof way is to append a version key of some sorts to the URL, such as a random ID.

```
<audio id="speech" src="speech.wav?ver=8976234asdfasdf">
```

There is likely another method though.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer, which confirms my suspicion: **caching**. To prevent the browser from caching the page (including audio), I modified the code:

```
<html>
<head>
// Add these two meta tags in order to set the caching off and never
// be cached again at expiration
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function Speak() {
    document.getElementById("Speech").load();
    document.getElementById("Speech").play();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<audio id="Speech" src="speech.wav"></audio>
<button type="button" onclick="Speak()">Speak</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Now it works correctly every time I change the content of `speech.wav`.